# How to check if a button is clicked or not?

Tags: android, xml

I have a Activity in android that has 4 buttons.
The first 3 buttons fetches a json data from a weather API for 1 day, next 5 days and next 10 days respectively.

I have a 4th button placed at the bottom of the screen, which takes user to second activity.
I want to restrict the entry of user to second Activity if no button from top 3 is clicked.

If the data is fetched, I mean any one of the top 3 buttons have been clicked, allow him to go to second activity on 4th button click else show a message.

How can i check on click of 4th button if any of the top 3 buttons have been clicked before?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put a boolean field in your activity, name it clicked and set it to false on the onCreate method of your first activity, then in the onClick method of your 3 buttons, set it to true, 
and in the onClick method of your 4th button check it, if it's true go startActivity, else launch a Toast

Comment: Perfect. Can't be simple then this.
How this skipped from my mind.
Thanks a lot YAT.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the 4th button look disable in "OnCreate" with the function "setEnabled"(may be wrong),
and then just set "setOnClickListener" for the 4th button when you click any of the others.

ps.
Can provide code example if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use if statement? You can keep the clicked count data under the first three buttons. Like this;

```
import java.util.stream.*;

int[] btnMemory = new int[4];

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     btnMemory[0] = 1;
                                     // your code

                }
            });
```

after, you can check it with if statement under 4th button;

```
button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int sum = IntStream.of(btnMemory).sum();
                 if(sum >= 3)
                                 // your code

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yeah this too can be done.
But I feel boolean is the best and standard way.

Comment: Your're right. I thought you wanted to use 4th button ,when all buttons clicked.

Comment: @MuhammedTanrıkulu what if it's only the first button which has been cllicked 4 times?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin Sure, fixed.